# Powershell Script for sending emails doesn't work, but no errors

Tags: powershell, smtp

i've been trying to build a small powershell script, to inform employees via email if their windows OS is not up to date, i was planning to use our own email relay to send those emails, so i wanted to use this script to test sending out the email

```
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer '<ip of email relay>' -To '<employee email>' -From '<central email>' -Subject 'test' -Body 'this is a test' -Port 25
```

now when i run this script powershell says the script has been executed, no errors, but the email is never sent/received.
Is there anything i'm missing here ?

edit: we are running hmailserver as our local smtp server

Comment: Does the email relay have any trace of the message submission?

Comment: it does yes, it says the email is queued, but as i'm answering you the day after trying and still haven't received an email, that seems a little odd to me

Comment: that probably means the relay is having trouble contacting the next mail server on the route. In any case, it's not a problem with Send-MailMessage

Comment: i've been digging around in the logfiles of our hmailserver, and i believe you are correct, so this topic would probably be more appropriate elsewhere right ?

Comment: I suspect you'll have better luck asking about troubleshooting SMTP/hMailServer on https://serverfault.com/, yes :)

Comment: i'll go do that then, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

The first step to review is.

If the central email user have enough permissions to relay email.

Then you could review if the pc or laptop where the script is executed is in the list of connections allowed to relay through the SMTP.
To Review this setting you need check the Route configuration in your email server.In this [link](https://www.hmailserver.com/documentation/v5.5/?page=reference_route) you will find the settings related on how and where emails for specific domains should be delivery

And you should review your client firewall make sure your firewall is not blocking port 25 or 587.

Comment: the central user does have permission to relay email, we use it for other smtp email notifications already, the client firewall should not be the issue either, since i already tried to run the script while it was deactivated and got the same result, as for your second point, where could i find this information ?